# Searchable textblock in adaptive card (Same behavior in manage tags add people)

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Good Day! I have a question, is it possible to have a searchable textblock in adaptive card? i have this feature to implement in a task module wherein if i type in a text in the textblock it will filter the result based on what i searched. kinda like the behaviour in managing the tag where you add some people. see image below:

I am looking for a way on how to replicate the same behaviour. maybe you guys can help me that would be great. Thank you.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATYSU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible right now there's an open issue for this here:
https://portal.productboard.com/adaptivecards/1-adaptive-cards-features/c/15-input-choiceset-auto-complete

You can upvote it, its already planned just not finished yet.

Comment: Too bad on my side yet so good in the future :) . Thanks for answering my question thou appreciate it.